# Inferring generic types from one method to another

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types

I'm looking for a way to do this:

```
var instanceOfMyClass = new MyClass();

instanceOfMyClass.AMethod<AType>(x => x.AnotherMethod(y => y.PropertyOfATypeClass));
```

I can do this but i need to explicitly specify the type for another class, like so:

```
instanceOfMyClass.AMethod<AType>(x => x.AnotherMethod<AType>(y => y.PropertyOfATypeClass));
```

Is there a way to do this without needing to rewrite the AType?

The AnotherMethod signature, by now, is:

```
AnotherMethod<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>>)
```

where that

```
<T>
```

would be the same AType from "AMethod"

The "AnotherMethod" is defined in the same class as "AMethod".

I need the AMethod's signature.

Comment: Please provide the signatures for `MyClass.AMethod`, `MyOtherClass.AnotherMethod`, `MyOtherOtherClass.PropertyofATypeClass` (where I don't know what the names of the types `MyOtherClass` and `MyOtherOtherClass` actually are because I can't tell the types of `x` and `y` in your lambda expressions).

Comment: What's the definition of the delegate that AMethod<T>() takes as an argument?

Comment: Generic type inference is based on the parameters - we'd need a very clear example to see...

Comment: The question is "what would be those signatures methods?"

Comment: We really need more code than this.  What's AMethod's signature?  Is AnotherMethod defined in AType?

Comment: That's exactly what i need, the AMethod's signature, thats what im looking for. And no, the AnotherMethod is defined in the same class as AMethod.

Comment: So AnotherMethod and AMethod are defined in MyClass in your example above?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have encountered one of the limitations of the C# type inference engine.

The crux of issue is that, in the general case of method group type inference, in order to do type inference on the parameters of a method that takes generic delegates, the compiler needs to know the method signature (to determine which types of delegates there are overloads for); but to determine the method signature, it needs to know the types of your delegate parameters. Thus, its possible for the compiler to get into a cyclical process. To avoid this, the compiler won't even try to do the inference.

For a much more accurate, detailed, and well-written explanation, [see this blog post.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/05/c-3-0-return-type-inference-does-not-work-on-member-groups.aspx)

And I think the short answer is, no, there's no way to avoid re-specifying the generic type.

Comment: Part of it depends on the structure of his code, though.  Obviously it's not working for him, but I wonder if he could restructure his code differently to allow the inference engine to work for him (though we'd need to see his code first...)

Comment: Note that we did make some improvements to this algorithm in C# 4. I should update that blog post to clarify. That said, I agree that in this case, the problem is not solvable by type inference.